# Initial value for mat-select from within template

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do you pass an initial value to a mat-select, from within a template.

This snippet is within an ngFor so I cannot set the value from the component, only the template!

```js
  /** Compare two status' to see if they are the same */
  compareStatus(obj1, obj2){
    console.log(obj1, obj2);
    return (obj1 && obj2) ? obj1.status === obj2.status : false;
  }
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Status"
    [formControl]="statusForm"
    floatLabel="never"
    name="status"
    [value]="{status: booking.status}"
    [compareWith]="compareStatus"
    id="status">
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: null, booking: booking._id }">
     No Status
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'checked', booking: booking._id }">
     Checked In
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'paid', booking: booking._id }">
     Paid
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'ticket', booking: booking._id }">
     Ticket
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'voucher', booking: booking._id }">
     Voucher
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'dna', booking: booking._id }">
     Did Not Attend
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

the `console.log` always shows `obj2` as `null` so I don't think the value is being properly set on the select

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: P.S. It's a bad idea for an option to be a JavaScript object. And do you have a Stackblitz demo?

Comment: works fine for me, why is it a bad idea ? plus they use objects in the angular material demos

Comment: If it works, then could you post a Stackblitz demo?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt4wa5?file=app%2Fselect-optgroup-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a `FormControl` and use `value` either to initialize (as you have done) or to bind. To initialize the select value, set in on the FormControl:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Status"
    [formControl]="statusForm"
    floatLabel="never"
    name="status"
    [compareWith]="compareStatus"
    id="status">
```

TS:

```
statusForm = new FormControl({status: booking.status});
```

Comment: I can't do this as the form control is within a ngFor so there are multiple, I need to do it from within the template.

Comment: You were correct G.Tranter I ended up having to use the `(selectionChange)` output to perform my actions rather than `formControl.valueChanges.subscribe`

Answer (score 0):

following the hint from @g-tranter , here is what I used as the solution

```js
<mat-select placeholder="Status"
   floatLabel="never"
   name="status"
   #status
   [value]="{status: booking.status}"
   [compareWith]="compareStatus"
   id="status"
   (selectionChange)="this.saveStatus(status.value)">
  <mat-option [value]="{ status: null, booking: booking._id }">
      No Status
   </mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'checked', booking: booking._id }">
      Checked In
   </mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'paid', booking: booking._id }">
      Paid
   </mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'ticket', booking: booking._id }">
      Ticket
   </mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'voucher', booking: booking._id }">
      Voucher
   </mat-option>
   <mat-option [value]="{ status: 'dna', booking: booking._id }">
      Did Not Attend
   </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```